# Load data on scroll down in Django

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I am currently working on a web application to feature the interface in django and how the content loads.

In my database, potentially thousands of these entries, and I want to make sure that only has to load a given number at a time to reduce stress on the servers etc.

lets say I have 5000 records and initially Load a given number of objects.
then load the next set of records once the I reaches the record at the bottom of the screen.

views.html:

```
def list(request):
    list_data = Container.objects.all()
    return render(request,
                  'list.html',
                  {'list_data': list_data,})
```

list.html:

```
{

% block content %}

<table border="1" >
    <tr>
        <th>list name</th>
        <th>received</th>
        <th>student name</th>
    </tr>

    {% for list_item in list_data %}
    <tr>
        <td>{{ list_item.serial_number}}</td>
        <td>{{ list_item.received}}</td>
        <td>{{list_item.studentss}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
{% endblock %}
```

I have this table in my view which contains large number of data.How do I change these so that I can use scroll down in Django??

Note: I don't want to use pagination to load the data.

Answer (score 3):

I believe this combines the django pagination, but utilizes it in an ajax function to add to the existing page without a reload:

http://django-endless-pagination.readthedocs.org/en/latest/twitter_pagination.html

Comment: Basically you should have inbox_template.html that contains everything up to and after the for loop.  Then a inbox_items.html that is only the for loop.  inbox_template will have the javascript includes etc, then just use the view with the variable/Model names changed from the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

For Django 1.8 and above use:

**Django EL(Endless) Pagination:**

> This app django-el-pagination created from
>   django-endless-pagination==2.0.

https://github.com/shtalinberg/django-el-pagination

**Django Endless Pagination** says:

> This project is abandoned.
>
> Thanks to the community that supported django-endless-pagination over
>   time. I do not have time to properly maintain and develop this
>   application. From now on, please use one of the great forks like
>   https://github.com/shtalinberg/django-el-pagination